# The bean 'metaDataSourceAdvisor', defined in null, could not be registered

Tags: spring-boot

I've updated the Spring Boot version from 2.0.3 to 2.1.1 but I'm getting this:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

The bean 'metaDataSourceAdvisor', defined in null, could not be registered. A bean with that name has already been defined in null and overriding is disabled.

Action:

Consider renaming one of the beans or enabling overriding by setting spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true
```

I get the error - the problem is that `defined in null` is not really a good pointer where to look. I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51367566/trouble-when-changing-spring-boot-version-from-2-0-3-release-to-2-1-0-build-snap) but I'd actually prefer to keep disallowing overriding ambiguous beans.

Any ideas?

---

**Log output**

```
2019-01-06 07:33:39.282  INFO 29626 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
2019-01-06 07:33:39.282  INFO 29626 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
2019-01-06 07:33:39.912  INFO 29626 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2019-01-06 07:33:39.997  INFO 29626 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 80ms. Found 23 repository interfaces.
2019-01-06 07:33:39.999  WARN 29626 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionOverrideException: Invalid bean definition with name 'metaDataSourceAdvisor' defined in null: Cannot register bean definition [Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityMetadataSourceAdvisor]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null] for bean 'metaDataSourceAdvisor': There is already [Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityMetadataSourceAdvisor]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null] bound.
2019-01-06 07:33:40.008  INFO 29626 --- [  restartedMain] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2019-01-06 07:33:40.010 ERROR 29626 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   :
```

Answer (score 125, accepted):

Okay, I found the issue myself: I had `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity` twice in my project:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true) // <--
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
}
```

and

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"mz.server.spring.repository"})
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, proxyTargetClass = true) // <--
@EntityScan(basePackages = "mz.server.hibernate.model")
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableScheduling
public class Application {
}
```

So that's a nice new Spring Boot feature I'd say.

Just watch out for unwanted duplicate annotations if you see this kind of error.

Answer (score 35):

Expanding on the accepted answer, as per the [release notes](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.1-Release-Notes#bean-overriding) for Spring Boot 2.1

> Bean overriding has been disabled by default to prevent a bean being accidentally overridden. If you are relying on overriding, you will need to set spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding to true.

So if you have used @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity more than once in your codebase and these beans are part of the same component scan then this annotation will attempt to create the metaDataSourceAdvisor bean more than once. This will throw an exception during initialization.

This will also apply to other auto configuration annotations that create beans. Make sure to only use their enabling annotations *once*.

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have missed adding following annotations (whichever applicable)

1. @EnableJpaRepositories({"com.base.package"})
2. @EnableMongoRepositories({"com.base.package"})

This worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I tried all these answers. But I noticed that error terminal says  `spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true` in your properties. Just do it it worked for me.

Comment: Only if you know what you're doing here and if you really want to allow overriding. This can deliver unexpected results as well.

Answer (score -4):

Can help "clean" and "build" project in Gradle or Maven.

Comment: I faced the same issue like author. I use Gradle and I cleaned my project then build it again and its helped.