# Is spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true a bad practice

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am building a Spring Boot Rest API server to port a legacy application on a more robust framework. That is my first project using those technologies. So far I have built a proof of concept with 2 API that reply "Hello world!" in JSON. One is open and the other is secured with OAuth2. I am done tuning the security up to the requirement.

I have also built a strong test structure using a combination of Rest-Assured for integration tests and Spring MockMvc for unit tests, so I am confident I am ready to start implementing real API using a TDD approach.

We are using Maven. My problem is that as soon as I had a dependency with our existing artifacts, I get the following stack. I understand what it means but our codebase is huge and I can't find out where this comes from. When I ask Google about this problem, I often find result simply suggesting to add `spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true` to my properties. Isn't this just sweeping the problem under the rug ? I would guess there is a very good reason why Spring doesn't allow this by default. What are the possible consequences of simply ignoring that error with a convenient application properties ?

The stack :

```
*************************** APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

The bean 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor', defined in class path resource [org/springframework/transaction/annotation/ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration.class], could not be registered. A bean with that name has already been defined in null and overriding is disabled.

Action:

Consider renaming one of the beans or enabling overriding by setting spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true

[WARNING]  java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run (AbstractRunMojo.java:558)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:748) Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionOverrideException: Invalid bean definition with name 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/transaction/annotation/ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration.class]: Cannot register bean definition [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration; factoryMethodName=transactionAdvisor; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/transaction/annotation/ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration.class]] for bean 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor': There is already [Root bean: class [org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.BeanFactoryTransactionAttributeSourceAdvisor]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null] bound.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.registerBeanDefinition (DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:897)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForBeanMethod (ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:274)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass (ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:141)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions (ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:117)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions (ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:327)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry (ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:232)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors (PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:275)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors (PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:95)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors (AbstractApplicationContext.java:705)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh (AbstractApplicationContext.java:531)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh (ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh (SpringApplication.java:775)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext (SpringApplication.java:397)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run (SpringApplication.java:316)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run (SpringApplication.java:1260)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run (SpringApplication.java:1248)
    at ca.mycompany.oav.ResourceServerApplication.main (ResourceServerApplication.java:22)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run (AbstractRunMojo.java:558)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Some spring defaults seem better reasoned than others (looking at you, OSIV) but this one seems sensible. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54059222/217324) seems relevant.

Comment: I've never used it.  Feels like you should review your bean definitions.

Answer (score 5):

Just to be aware that: by adding this, **it is difficult to guess which bean will have priority because the bean creation order is determined by dependency relationships mostly influenced in runtime.** Therefore, allowing bean overriding can produce unexpected behavior unless we know the dependency hierarchy of our beans well enough.

[Reference](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-bean-definition-override-exception#4-beans-coming-from-3rd-party-libraries)

Answer (score 1):

`spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true` concerns overriding beans *using the same bean name* as an existing bean. If the bean is in your own code, you can always just change the bean name (if using `@Bean`, the name is by default the method name, or the class name for `@Component`; but there are different ways to set the bean name, check the docs).

So the only reasonable (as far as I can think) reason to set this flag is if multiple beans that you don't control (i.e. from 3rd party code) are loaded with the same name.

Comment: Note that in case you're having multiple beans with the same type, autowiring this bean without using a name/qualifier will cause initialization to crash.

Answer (score 0):

Answer is

> **No don't use overriding as much as possible**. But at times may be (but with caution)

To understand this better,

When you start the  Application, Spring Boot auto-loads many beans (to provide out-of-the-box functionalities) some may be required some may not be. There are two options we have

**Option #1:**

1. Let Spring Boot Load the functionality
2. You later override

**Option #2:**

1. Ask Spring Boot not to load what you don't need.
2. Just add your own bean

### Example Use-case

Spring Boot provides  out of the box Cloud Configuration with ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator. in a realtime scenario, we will have our own secured config server to use instead of the default one.

**Option #1:**

1. Let Spring Boot Load ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator Bean
2. Enable overriding by specifying `spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true`
3. Define you custom Bean, But make sure you add @Order, @Primary etc.

**Option #2:**

1. Ask Spring Boot not load ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator by adding `spring.cloud.config.enabled=false`
2. Just Define you custom Bean.

You save startup time also code looks clean.

Ref: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/issues/177

Comment: This answer is somewhat incorrect (or at least misleading), because `spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true` concerns overriding existing beans *with the same bean name*. Your example is about overriding with the same bean type, which is always allowed.

Comment: Yes. It is completely allowed to override by name or by priority. 

Nut Idea is to avoid overriding as much as possible . If we have option disable the default behaviour and load your custom components.