# Spring bean duplication: "The bean defined in null, could not be registered". Can't find it

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

I'm writing a simple Spring JPA test application and getting error: *"The bean 'userRepository', defined in null, could not be registered. A bean with that name has already been defined in null and overriding is disabled."*. I understand that it points on bean duplications but I'm really confused where the hell duplication is. Just turning on bean overriding is not good choise I guess.
Please, help.

The app's structure is:

**User class**

```
package com.mot.platform.bean;

import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name="plan_user")
public class User {

   @Id
   @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
   private Long id;

   @Column(name = "name", length = 255, nullable = false)
   private String name;

   @Column(name = "password", length = 255, nullable = false)
   private String password;

   public Long getId() {
      return id;
   }

   public void setId(Long id) {
      this.id = id;
   }  

   public String getName() {
      return name;
   }

   public void setName(String name) {
      this.name = name;
   }

   public String getPassword() {
      return password;
   }

   public void setPassword(String password) {
      this.password = password;
   }
}
'''

**UserRepository class**<br />
'''
package com.mot.platform.model;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import com.mot.platform.bean.User;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {
    //User findById(long id);
}
```

**UserService class**

```
package com.mot.platform.model;

import com.mot.platform.bean.User;

public interface UserService {

    public void addUser (String name, String password);
    public User getUserById (Long id);

}
```

**UserServiceImpl class**

```
UserServiceImpl

package com.mot.platform.model;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.mot.platform.bean.User;
import java.util.Optional;

@Service
public class UsrServiceImpl implements UserService {

  //  @Autowired
    private UserRepository rep;

    public void addUser(String name, String password) {
        User user = new User();
        user.setName("TestHiber");
        user.setPassword("ttt");
        rep.save(user);
    }

    public User getUserById(Long id) {
        Optional<User> optusr = rep.findById(id);
        User usr = optusr.isPresent() ? optusr.get() : null;
        return usr;
     }
}
```

**UserRepository**

```
package com.motivation.platform.model;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import com.mot.platform.bean.User;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {
  }
```

**application.properties**

```
# ===============================
# DATABASE
# ===============================
spring.datasource.driver-class-name= oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:1521:BDSM
spring.datasource.username=XXX
spring.datasource.password=YYY
# ===============================
# JPA / HIBERNATE
# ===============================
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle9Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

I don't have another files/classes besides attached here.

Comment: What about `UserRepository`'s code?

Comment: Why is `//  @Autowired` a comment in `UsrServiceImpl` ?

Comment: This is a configuration issue . Do go through this [SO q & a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54059222/the-bean-metadatasourceadvisor-defined-in-null-could-not-be-registered)

Comment: Probably you have used `@EnableJpaRepositories` annotation more than once somewhere in your configuration class.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to attach UserRepository code. Its empty for now. Added user repository code.

Comment: Change or rename your repository package to `package com.mot.platform.model;`

Comment: The problem is not in the code you are showing. You should look for a duplicate in conf annotations.

Comment: Uncomment '@Autowired ' in  `UsrServiceImpl `

Comment: @alex valuiskyi
I uncommented '@Autowired' for UserServiceImpl. It wasnt commented before. It's not affecting on error.

Comment: @gnana jeyam95  Tried to do this with no success :(

Comment: @Abdullah Khan  I moved all anothers classes outside app (java folder) .

Comment: @Tristan I dont have any configuration elsware besides application.properties  (attached it)